# How to change date and time format on Marshmallow?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, date-and-time

I'm using a Nexus 5X with Android 6.0.1, patch level January 2016. I'd like to change the system language to English but like to keep my local date format. In versions prior to Marshmallow, there was an option to set the date format, but I can find it anymore...

How do I set the UI language to English and the date format to DD.MM.YYYY or YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: I recently downloaded android marshmallow on my phone and there is only one English to select for language but you can select English UK, English US or English AU for keyboard input. Unfortunately changing the keyboard input to another English than US does not change the date format from US layout mm/dd/yyyy. Selecting another language changes the layout but the only English available to pick must be US version.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Android Marshmallow you don't seem to be able to change the date format. Instead it chooses automatically what's appropriate for your locale.

In your case, you seem to want the English (UK) variant and not the English (US) one. So go to language settings and change it. Any other English variant should work since I'm pretty sure only americans use the MM/DD/YYYY variant.

Comment: But dd/mm/yyyy is not sane either. How can I get ISO 8601 dates (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Comment: I want the ISO format which is the proper standard format. I don't think Android is guessing correctly when it displays the date in the worst format it could choose. The one who decided that it shouldn't be allowed to choose the format and that the system could guess such preferences don't really know much about software design and development.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  Go to Language settings and check if your set on English  (United States).

Comment: How does that change the date format to something sane?

Comment: @MaxRied I think greg's trying to make the point that English (United States) uses MM-DD-YYYY, while English (UK) and some other English locales use DD-MM-YYYY. If a non-US English locale suits your needs in other ways, you can choose it to get the date format you want.